# Pass multiple account variables to single parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am building a financial report.  Months as columns, department/account as rows, summing transactions:

[image]

I am able to expand departments and see totals by account, I am also able to click on a single account amount and drill through to another report for transactional detail. Say account 70300 for March totaling 14,244.  This work wells.  The report successfully passes Department 000, account 70300, 201503 for March 2015, showing me the transactional detail for the account.

[image]

My issue is being able to drill through for a department, say the 1,063,038 for department 000 for March.  I am able to click on the value and pass it actually passes all the accounts with data for the month to the filter Acct, however it returns no data:

[image]

I thought it would have something to do with how the separator is stringing the accounts together in my expression.  I have tried `“,”` and `“, “`.  Looking at other reports I have created with multiple criteria selection from a drop down list it always displays selections separated with a comma then a space but that is not working for me.  Here is the expression I am using via Text Box Properites -> Action -> Expression:

```
=IIF(Inscope("matrix1_G_L_Account_No_"),Fields!G_L_Account_No_.Value,Join(LookupSet(Fields!Global_Dimension_2_Code.Value, Fields!Global_Dimension_2_Code.Value, Fields!G_L_Account_No_.Value, "DataSet1"),","))
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your **Account_No** a string? Is so, I think you'd need quotes around each - , "DataSet1"),"**""**, **""**")).

Comment: G_L_Account_No_ is a field returned in DataSet1.  It is the Acct number in the report.  Such as 70300.  If I add an extra set of double quotes as it appears you suggest it passes accounts like this 70200", "70300", "71100","71109.  I miss the quotes at the beginning and end.  The report still shows no transactional data.

Comment: Is the Acct parameter a string or INTEGER? If it's a string and it's used in the SQL (in the **Dataset parameter** and not the dataset filter), it would be a single quote - not double quotes "', '". I'm guessing that it's a string since your report left-justified the Acct Number. You'd also need to add **"'" &** to the begining of the string for the first quote and another for the end **& "'"**.

Comment: In the SQL table it is a string (varchar).  I have done nothing in my sql to convert it so it should still be a string, although I am not 100% sure how to verify it in SSRS.  Unless you mean under the Parameters under the detail report.  It is set to "Text" currently for Acct.  Regardless, I tried it with double quotes as well as single quotes, making sure to add it to the front and back '70200', '70300', '71100','71109' and then "70200", "70300", "71100","71109".  That is what I see in the parameter selection that is passed to the detail report.  Still no data.

Comment: In your transaction detail report, is the "Acct" parameter set to be multi-valued? And is the query for the report dataset written to accept a multivalued parameter (e.g. Acct IN(@Acct), not Acct = @Acct)?

Comment: Acct parameter is set to "Allow Multiple Values" in the transaction detail report.  The query was actuall not set to accept a multivalued parameter.  I changed it to Acct IN (@Acct). Thank you for checking that.  After making the change I went back tried my original expression (in OP), as well as what Hannover Fist suggested with both double quotes as well as single quotes around each account.  Still no data.

Comment: Depending on how you have set up your tablix, you might need to pass different parameters to the subreport based on what grouping level the user has clicked on. E.g. when the user clicks on the 1,063,038 you only need to pass Department and Date to your subreport, because all accounts are included. There's an example of this here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b561187-1131-400c-85cc-7219c0b684e4/issues-passing-drillthrough-parameters-from-a-multilevel-tablix-in-ssrs-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices